# Ruby on Rails with JQuery Sortable problems

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I've searched all over for a solution to this but could not find one that fit my specific problem, or that I could understand. I have an RoR app that allows people to cast a "vote" on an "election" using a drag and drop interface, using JQuery UI's Sortable. I call each element on the drag and drop list a "preference". All "preferences" start in the unsorted (sortable2) column, and the user will drag them over to the sorted column (sortable1). I want to save only the positions of the "preferences" that the user dragged into "sortable1".

For the drag and drop, I used JQuery UI's Sortable, and the interface is quite nice. However, I am having problems actually submitting the position of each preference to eventually record it in the database. This is my first web app and I am very new to this. Thank you so much in advance for help. Here is the code that I have:

In the view for creating a new vote:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $( "ul.droptrue" ).sortable({
  connectWith: "ul"
});

$( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).disableSelection();
});
```

```
<ul id="sortable1" class='droptrue'>
Preferences:

</ul>

<ul id="sortable2" class='droptrue'>
Unranked candidates:
  <% @vote.preferences.each do |preference| %>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>      
    <%= preference.candidate.name %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

From advice I found online, I added 'sort' to my votes_controller.rb:

```
class VotesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :json

  # I added this 
  def sort
      params[:preferences].each_with_index do |id, index|
         @vote.preferences.update(['position=?', index+1], ['id=?', id])
      end
      render nothing: true
  end
```

In vote.rb, I have:

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
    # ...
    has_many :preferences
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :preferences, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: lambda { |c| c.values.all?(&:blank?) }
end
```

In preference.rb, I have:

```
class Preference < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :position
   belongs_to :vote, dependent: :destroy
end
```

In routes.rb, I have:

```
resources :votes do
   put :sort
end
```

Honestly it would make my day if someone would be my hero and help a brother out. I searched for quite long to avoid posting something that might be redundant, but everything I found on here and through google could not help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The way we are doing is:

1. Use ['stop' event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#event-stop) on "sortable".
2. In the stop event, iterate through all elements of "ul" with index. Index is the "sorted position" of items.
3. Make an ajax POST to modify the positions of all items.